# Obtain raw value "val()" data of parent node from a child reference in Cloud Functions Realtime Database

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Let's say I'm pointing at a path as follow in my typescript/javascript code function:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('shops/countries/{countryName}/shopAddress/{currentShopAddress}')
.onWrite((snapshot,context) => {

    // Is it possible to get the data raw value from a child reference node? 
    // For example: 
    const countryName = snapshot.before.parent('countryName').val();
    // Then
    const countryId = countryName['countryId'];
})
```

I'm a node.js/typescript and firebase cloud functions newbie :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data for parent nodes from the database is not automatically passed into your Cloud Function, as that you be a potentially large amount of unneeded data.

If you need it, you'll need to load it yourself. Luckily this is not all that hard:

```
const countryRef = snapshot.ref.parent.parent;
const countryName = countryRef.key; // also available as context.params.countryName
countryRef.child('countryId').once('value').then((countryIdSnapshot) => {
  const countryId = countryIdSnapshot.val();
});
```

Note that, since your asynchronously loading additional data, you'll need to return a promise to ensure your function doesn't get shut down prematurely.

Comment: snap.parent.parent or snap.parent does not exist

Comment: OK. Fixed that typo.